# how to use vpc endpoint with ses in serverless

Tags: serverless, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have functions deployed in vpc which doesn't have nat gateway/ internet access.
Goal: Send email through SES from this function (in vpc)

I have tried using public private subnet with nat gateway to send emails and it works fine. But i am trying to use it vi VPC endpoint. i have created an email vpc endpoint but not sure how to configure it in serverless.yml. Have tried setting up configs as said in 
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

but nothing working because there is no mention for ses.

Comment: Hi Shubham, just wondering where the Serverless part comes in as you've stated that you goal is to send an email through SES from a function in a VPC. Are you planning to migrate this function to Serverless Lambda at a later point?

Comment: lambda code is written in serverless framework in nodejs. its not plain aws lambda

Comment: I can understand your frustration as I went through a very similar thing myself recently. I willl share what I learnt and built. Hopefully it will get you going.

Answer (score 5):

You need the following configuration so that CloudFormation creates the resource. (Note the variables in brackets)

```
resources:
  Resources:  
    VPCEndpointForSES:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
      Properties:
        PrivateDnsEnabled: True
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - <ID of the VPC Security Group>
        ServiceName: 'com.amazonaws.<AWS Region String>.email-smtp'
        SubnetIds:
          - <Subnet of your VPC>
          - <Subnet of your VPC>
          - <Subnet of your VPC>
        VpcEndpointType: Interface
        VpcId: <ID of your VPC>
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. All the other Stack Overflow responses talk about how complicated it is to set up a VPC Endpoint, and appear to imply that you need to start an EC2 instance. I am using SAM, and this was all I needed to add the VPC endpoint to my build. Then, as @Amir Babic says, don't use the SES API, go into SES on your AWS Dashboard and create an SMTP login. This will give you credentials that you can use with any SMTP library, e.g. net/smtp in Go.

Comment: @user1527225 there is no way to create such SMTP login via Cloudformation as well?

Comment: @tteguayco - ChatGPT seems to think you can. Try "How do I use AWS CloudFormation to create an SMTP login using the AWS SES API"

Answer (score 4):

You must use the AWS SES SMTP endpoint because AWS does not support VPC private endpoint for AWS SES API.

Guidance for configuration AWS SES SMTP with private VPC endpoint:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html

List of available AWS services that integrate with AWS PrivateLink (or private VPC endpoint can be created):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/integrated-services-vpce-list.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at AWS PrivateLink for VPC Endpoints?

You won't need to set up an Internet gateway, NAT device, VPN connection, or AWS Direct Connect connection. Your VPC can communicate with AWS SES within the Amazon network using AWS PrivateLink.

Note that VPC Endpoints currently do not support cross-region requests—ensure that you create your endpoint in the same region in which you plan to issue your API calls to Amazon SES.

You will need to create a security group and a VPC Interface Point. There's a step by step example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-for-vpc-endpoints/)

Additional Resources:  [AWS PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/) [Interface Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html)