# AWS Lambda triggers SES in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a lambda function sitting in a VPC, with the following in/out bound rules.
[image: Inbound Rule]

[image: OutBound Rule]

Inside the function, the goal is to trigger an email, so something like this:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'us-west-2' });
                
ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

However; when I trigger the function, there is no error printed, and the task timed out.

Originally the function was sitting out of VPC, and it can successfully send the email.

I've double checked this function's permission, which includes AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.

Any one knows what's happening here?

Comment: If posted possible answer from tom_139 , not working or possible for you to implement. I would suggest to check VPC flow logs of your lambda's network interface for more details. At times if it is some organization account,  then some network firewall rules such as security group or NACL or even you http proxy block such a network traffic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem with this is that the lambda function's code has no path to reach the SES endpoint.

The easiest way to fix this is to give the function access to the Internet.
Although you gave the Security Group permission to connect to the internet, cannot reach the SES endpoint because it has no public IP to send the requests from.

#### Putting Function behind NAT

The easiest way to fix this is to:

1. put a **NAT Gateway** in the subnet(s) where the function is deployed to,
2. in the route table of the subnet(s) append a rule to direct all traffic to `0.0.0.0/0` to the NAT Gateway.

More info about [NAT gateways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)

Keep in mind that this has the advantage to allow your function to access any internet resource and also the downside of routing the traffic though public Internet.

#### Creating an endpoint in your VPC

*This solution, although cleaner and more modern, involves many steps and I suggest you to stick with the first solution.*

A VPC endpoint is essentially a way to reach an AWS service (or a service from AWS's Marketplace) without letting your traffic to leave your VPC.

This works by assigning a private IP in your VPC to a "private link" to that service.

If you want to take this path, start reading from this page [Interface VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html).

Comment: If you are using SAM, it is incredibly easy to create a VPC endpoint for SES, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62774673/how-to-use-vpc-endpoint-with-ses-in-serverless#answer-65500743
Then you go to SES in the AWS Dashboard, and generate SMTP credentials. Then to invoke it, you use a regular SMTP library (e.g. Go's net/smtp) and not the AWS SES API.

Answer (score 4):

I did a lot of research how to solve the "Lambda won't be able to access internet/SES/S3/..." issue, because **I don't want to spend money on a NAT Gateway**. Here is my solution.

1. You need 2 Lambdas (1 in the VPC and 1 outside of the VPC)
2. My first Lambda does the VPC jobs (in my case request RDS)
3. The result of my first lambda I post to an SNS topic (You need to set [VPC endpoint for SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/endpoint-services-overview.html))
4. A SQS queue is subscribed to the SNS topic
5. My second Lambda listens to the SQS queue and does the rest of the "Internet job"

Like this I do not have to setup a NAT gateway and save those 30 bucks each month . And like this you can call SES functions like `listIdentity` and so on...